# how to store a value to a variable while in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm programming a calculator.

For example, I have the following:

```
result = 0
splitted_calculation = ["2", "+", "2"]
for thing in splited_calculation:
    if thing == "+":
        result = result + number
    else:
        number = int(thing)
print(result)
```

I want that, if the variable in the for loop is an integer, then that value is stored such that I can add the previous integer to the next integer currently in the for loop. However, when I run the code, I always get 0. It seems that the "number = int(thing)" isn't working. Any tips to solve this?

Comment: The shown code has a typo ("splitted" vs. "splited") and fails with an error. After correcting the typo it prints 2.

Comment: Even when you fix the typo, the final `number = int(thing)` isn't going to do anything. `result` will be `2` and not `4`.

Comment: Try simplifying even more and ask specific questions if you don't see the problem or find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code (besides the typo) is that the last digit is ignored. Step through it - in your head, on paper, or with a debugger.

Iterations of the loop. For this example, change it to `['2','+','3']` for clarity:

| SIteration | `thing` | Action | `number` | `result` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | assign it to `number` | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | + | add `number` to `result` | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | assign it to `number` | 3 | 2 |

After the loop, the last digit is just hanging out in `number` but was never added to `result`. So `result` ends up at `2` not `5`.

If the format is always "number operator number" there is no need for a loop. Access the values directly from the list:

```
splitted_calculation = ["2", "+", "2"]
left_number = int(splitted_calculation[0])
right_number = int(splitted_calculation[2])
operator = splitted_calculation[1]
if operator == '+':
    result = left_number + right_number
elif operator == '-'
    result = left_number - right_number
# repeat for others.
```

If the formulas are more complex ("2 + 2 + 2" for example) you can modify the loop to store the last operator and do the math on the numbers:

```
splitted_calculation = ["-5", "+", "2", "-", "3"]
result = 0
last_op = "+"
for n in splitted_calculation:
    if n in "+-*/":
        last_op = n
    else:
        if last_op == '+': result += int(n)
        elif last_op == '-': result -= int(n)
        elif last_op == '*': result *= int(n)
        elif last_op == '/': result /= int(n)
```

Output:

```
-6
```

Answer (score -2):

Find Modified Code Below:

```py
result = 0
splited_calculation = ["2", "+", "2"]
for thing in splited_calculation:
    if thing != "+":
       result += int(thing)

print(result)
```

Comment: any issues here?